# Set EKAlarm in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I m trying to set alarm from app with my audio file but getting lots of messages like

**Use of undeclared identifier EKAlarm**

**Unknown receiver EKEvent did you mean UIEvent**

**Member reference base type 'int" is not a structure or union**

```
 @property (retain, nonatomic) EKAlarm *alarm;

 @synthesize alarm;

-(void) AlarmAction:(id)sender{

EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-300];


[EKEvent addAlarm:alarm];
alarm.soundName =
  }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the EventKit framework?  It must be added under `Link Binary With Libraries` under the `Build Phases` tab of your project properties.

======
EDIT:

You should be using UILocalNotification ([Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). You should:

- Create an instance of UILocalNotification,
- Set the `fireDate` property to the time you would like the alarm to fire,
- If desired, set the `repeatInterval` to some NSCalendarUnit (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit)),
- Set the `soundName` property to the file name of the audio file you wish to play,
- Finally, schedule it with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: myNotification];`

Comment: i do have EvenKit framework in BuildPhase in Link Binary With Libraries but not subclassed EKEvent

Comment: subclassed ekevent but getting message that cannot find interface declaration for ekevent of alarm

Comment: added #import <EventKit/EventKit.h> that makes message go away

Comment: My apologies, I forgot that EKEvent is a subclass of EKCalanderItem, which does have the addAlarm method.  Regardless, you would need to create an instance of EKEvent and then add the alarm: [myEvent addAlarm:alarm].

Comment: I have another question, though. What are you trying to set the alarm for? This type of alarm is used for Calendar events. If you are trying to set an alarm-clock type alert, you should be using NSLocalNotification to create a local notification.

Comment: i want to set alarm clock type alert for that i should be using UILocalNotification. Is there any example to use for reference.

Comment: Yes, I meant UILocalNotification. See my updated answer above.