# ios-how to make alarm with custom sound and snooze when app is active and inactive both

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have searched, and I found UILocalNotification, but it works only when app is not active and i can not implement custom sound and snooze. Here is my code

```
UILocalNotification* alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    alarm.fireDate = [myPicker date];
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    alarm.hasAction = YES;
    alarm.alertAction = @"SNOOZE";
    alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    alarm.soundName =  @"Notification.aif";
    alarm.alertBody = @"Alarm";
    //[app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: notification and alarm or totally different concept ?

Comment: if you want to use alarm use EKAlram https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKAlarmClassRef/index.html

Comment: i used ekalarm too, but cannot put custom sound there, is there any option? @codercat

Comment: soundName property is the name of a system sound that can be used with the soundNamed: class method

Comment: can you please show me a sample code of EKalarm with custom sound?

Comment: custom sound means ? you want use your own sound else system defaults sounds?

Comment: sorry you cant change alarm sound. if you want to use sound go ahead with your notification approach. +1 i give to you

Comment: this link is may be help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775954/set-ekalarm-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Approach is absolutely correct. but i thought you forgot some things about UILocalNotification .

read [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/)

A UILocalNotification object specifies a notification that an app can schedule for presentation at a specific date and time. The operating system is responsible for delivering local notifications at their scheduled times; the **app does not have to be running for this to happen**.

Comment: thanks, i have used UILocalNotification with my own sound name made another way to play it when app is active, in didReceiveLocalNotification

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i have used UILocalNotification with my own sound name made another way to play it when app is active, in didReceiveLocalNotification

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
    {
      NSLog(@"Received notification");
        // Play a sound and show an alert only if the application is active, to avoid doubly notifiying the user.
        if ([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
            NSLog(@"active");

          NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alarm2" ofType:@"wav"];
            NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, &_mySound);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.mySound);
        }

    }
```

Comment: if you are using uilocalnotification must to use badge count . did you used that ?

Comment: nope i am not using badge count for the application, but localnotification works without badge count, is it mandatory to use badgecount?

Comment: not mandatory. but it not good developing app. user wants know how many notification get from app. if your app show badge icon then only user go to open your app. so try it

Comment: UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

Comment: use above the code every time you fire the notification